# Automatic yes command when patching?

Tags: terminal, automation, linux-kernel, patch

I am trying to patch a kernel with the following command:

```
patch -p1 < 0001-Linux-3.4.4.patch
```

However i keep receiving y/n? responses such as:

```
The next patch would create the file arch/arm/mach-at91/pm_slowclock.S,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
```

I have tried to solve this issue by automating it with this command:

```
yes | patch -p1 < 0001-Linux-3.4.4.patch
```

However the terminal still prompts me with a y/n? response.
Can anyone help me out here? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to supply standard input to the `patch` command from two places at once: a pipe (`|`) from the output of `yes` and redirection (`<`) from a patch file. The redirection is performed after the pipeline is set up, so standard input will come from the patch file, not from the pipeline.

`patch` does not read the answers to its questions from standard input, it reads them directly from the controlling terminal device.

`patch` has a couple of options to skip asking questions:

- `-f` or `--force` will assume that patches are not reversed.
- `-t` or `--batch` will assume that patches that look reversed are reversed.

There is also a `-R` or `--reverse` option to explicitly indicate that the patch is reversed.